# Issue with multiple orderby values

Tags: order

I am using this:

```
'orderby' => array(
    'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 
    'menu_order' => 'ASC'
), 
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'newprice',
        'type' => 'decimal',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'datum',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => strtotime('-1days'),
    ),
),
```

Which works fine, except for the fact that this excludes any posts that don't contain a 'newprice' meta value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your meta query you also need explicitly query posts that don't have that meta key set. You can do this by nesting meta queries like so:

```
'orderby'    => array(
    'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 
    'menu_order'     => 'ASC'
), 
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'  => 'newprice',
            'type' => 'decimal',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'newprice',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'datum',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value'   => strtotime('-1days'),
    ),
),
```

<s>Also note that you need to set `'meta_key'` on the query so that when you `orderby` `'meta_value_num'` it orders by the right meta key.</s>

Actually, it doesn't seem to be necessary if you have a `meta_query`, and excluding it will save you a join.